# How can I cache a Directory on the local machine in Azure Devops Local Build Agents

Tags: caching, azure-devops

I have an Azure Dev Ops Local build agent Running on a server in my garage, and I'm trying to cache my rust target dir, so it builds faster.

The main issue is that the cache takes FOREVER to upload and download.

is it possible to cache it on the host machine instead? That way I get either localhost download speed or whatever speed the SSD can handle for copying.

thanks :)